# Strange behaviour when updating a Label with a TextField (Possible bug in JavaFX8)?

Tags: java, javafx

Sorry, I haven't found a better title to describe my problem:
I want to update a JavaFX label with the value of a `TextField`.

In a certain constellation, the already updated value won't show until I resize the window or click outside of the `GridPane` containing my Label and my `TextField`.
Once I've done that, the value will update immediately.

Every element in the following FXML seems to matter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?language javascript?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <fx:script> function updateLabel() { label.setText(textfield.getText()); } </fx:script>

    <GridPane>
        <TextField fx:id="textfield" onKeyReleased="updateLabel()" />
        <Label fx:id="label" text="Just type..." GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
        <DatePicker GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
    </GridPane>
    <!-- a ScrollPane containing a TableView containing a TableColumn -->
    <ScrollPane><TableView><columns><TableColumn/></columns></TableView></ScrollPane>
</VBox>
```

- If I remove the `DatePicker` or place it outside of the `GridPane`, the `Label` refreshes immediately.
- If I remove the `ScrollPane` or the `TableView`, the `Label` refreshes immediately

You can try this just by loading the FXML file like this (but you need JDK8 because of `DatePicker`):

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root =
            FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Is this a (known?) bug? Or am I missing something regarding cache strategies or something like that in JavaFX?

```
/opt/java8/bin % ./java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
/opt/java8/bin % uname -a       
Linux venus 3.15.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 28 20:06:17 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Works for me (OS X + [Java8u20b17](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)).  Also works if the javascript function is replaced with a bind for the label text: `text="${textfield.text}"`.

Comment: Yes. Same issue. My OS is Win 8. Java ver. 1.8.0. Solution would be easy. Just bind text property of `TextField` to text property of `Label`: `textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(label.textProperty());`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Indeed, the solution to this example is easy; but in the non-simplified version of my program, I'm entering a time into the TextField and adding 8h to it in the label - so a simple bind wouldn't be enough.

Comment: I cold also place the datepicker outside of the GridView - this would even solve the problem in the real application.

Comment: I've reported a bug: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38337

Comment: Associated bug report was closed as cannot reproduce with the comment "Confirmed: Happens in 8, does not happen in 8u20 and 8u40 dev."

Answer (score -1):

Since a label is usually static you probably need to call repaint on your stage. Can you add that to the update label method mentioned in the fxml?

Comment: This seems to be more a comment then a actual answer, since it's asking OP about his code